# create object function that generate properties to its caller object

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function inside an object. I need this function to generate setters and getters
for the properties of the caller object without generating getters or setters for the property of the function value.

I reached for something like this. But It gives me RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded.

```
function Emp() {
    return {
        name: "Mohamed",
        id: "5",
        getSetGen: function() {
            for (var i in this) {
                if (typeof this[i] !== 'function') {
                    (function(j) {
                        Object.defineProperty(this, j, {
                            get: function() {
                                return this[j];
                            },
                            set: function(val) {
                                this[j] = val
                            }
                        })
                    })(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to apply getSetGen() to  `var user = { name:”Ali”,age:10}`  for example.

Is there any possible solution? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
This is the text that describes what I need ...

Create your own custom object that has getSetGen as
function value, this function should generate setters and getters
for the properties of the caller object
This object may have description property of string value if
needed
Let any other created object can use this function property to
generate getters and setters for his own properties
Avoid generating getters or setters for property of function
value

Comment: Can you shed some more light on the exact requirement here? Like for example you successfully added the getters and setters, then calling them does what? I am specifically confused by `generate setters and getters for the properties of the caller object`.

Comment: @ rahulpsd18 This exactly describes what I want .. 

 Create your own custom object that has getSetGen as
function value, this function should generate setters and getters
for the properties of the caller object
This object may have description property of string value if
needed
Let any other created object can use this function property to
generate getters and setters for his own properties
Avoid generating getters or setters for the property of the function
value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In trying to solve this I reworked some of your code, but I think this does basically what you're looking for, and you can tweak it to your preferences.

(I think the issue was that the new accessor property had the same name as the existing data property. See comments in the code for further explanation.)

```js
const
  baseObj = getBaseObj(),
  user = { name: "Ali", age: 10 };
baseObj.addAccessorsForAllDataProps.call(user);

console.log("\nsetting age to 11...");
user.age = 11;

console.log("\nretrieving user age...");
console.log(user.age);


function getBaseObj(){
  return {
    name: "Mohamed",
    id: 5,
    addAccessorsForAllDataProps(){
      for(let originalPropName in this){
        if(!isFunction(this[originalPropName])){
          // Renames the data property with an underscore
          const dataPropName = `_${originalPropName}`
          // Binds existing value to renamed data property
          this[dataPropName] = this[originalPropName];
          // Passes originalPropName to be used as accessorPropName
          addAccessors(this, originalPropName, dataPropName);
        }
      }

      // Accessor prop can't have same name as data prop
      // (I think your stack overflow happened b/c getter got called infinitely)
      function addAccessors(obj, accessorPropName, dataPropName){
        Object.defineProperty(obj, accessorPropName, {
          get: function(){
            console.log("(getter invoked)"); // Just proving accessors get called
            return obj[dataPropName];
          },
          set: function(val){
            console.log("(setter invoked)");
            obj[dataPropName] = val;
          }
        });
      };
    }

  }
}

function isFunction(val) {
  return val && {}.toString.call(val) === '[object Function]';
}
```